# How to extend this particular multiplexer circuit to 4 x 4 channels in / 1 x 4 channels out?

Tags: digital-logic

How to extend this particular multiplexer circuit to 4 x 4 channels in / 1 x 4 channels out?
Forgive me my ignorance, I'm just a my very beginning with this stuff... Thank you!

[image: 4x3_channels_in-1x3_channels_out_mux]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your application, do you only want digital data to be multiplexed?

Answer (score 1):

YOu just have to add another 74HCT151, with its address lined in parallel wiht the existing '151s.

Comment: Thank you. I'll buy a breadboard an the compnents tomorrow & try if it works in principle.

Answer (score 0):

> What have you tried so far? What is your application, do you only want digital data to be multiplexed?<

To be honest, I only tried to figure out how that thing works. Found a good website meanwhile explaining that. I want to switch 2 I²S lines and 2 MCK lines (24.576 MHz).